# IText PDF Margin Border

Tags: java, itext

I want a border line for margin given to create PDF.

I have tried with following code. But it will not leave margin on all sides.

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Rectangle rect = document.getPageSize();
rect.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX); // left, right, top, bottom border
rect.setBorderWidth(1); // a width of 5 user units
rect.setBorderColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY); // a red border
rect.setUseVariableBorders(false); // the full width will be visible
canvas.rectangle(rect);
```

I also tried with this, but it is not working.

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.rectangle(5, 5, document.getPageSize().getWidth()-50, document.getPageSize().getHeight());
```

Suppose, I want to leave margin 40 all sides and than I want border. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet should work, unless a CropBox was defined. In case there's a cropbox, part of your rectangle will be ourside the visible area of your page.

A second problem with your first snippet concerns:

```
rect.setUseVariableBorders(false);
```

You have a borderwidth of 1, but as you don't use variable borders only 0.5pt will be seen, The other 0.5pt will be outside the visible area of your page.

The second snippet won't work because it is incomplete. You have forgotten to add the following line:

```
canvas.stroke();
```